# Jersey/REST: delegating requests to different sub resources without code duplication?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

We created a resource, like:

```
@Path("whatever")
public class WhateverResource {

@POST
public Response createWhatever(CreateBean bean) { ...

@DELETE
@Path("/{uuid}")
public void deleteWhatever(@PathParam("uuid") UUID uuid) { ...
```

and so on for GET, PUT, HEAD.

Now we figured that we figured that we need to check whether the underlying feature is actually enabled. A single check, and when it fails, all operations should simply result in a 501.

My first thought was be to duplicate the existing resource, like:

```
@Path("whatever")
public class WhateverResourceIsntAvailable {

@POST
public Response createWhatever(CreateBean bean) { 
  throw 501

@DELETE
@Path("/{uuid}")
public void deleteWhatever(@PathParam("uuid") UUID uuid) { 
  throw 501
```

So, two resources, both specifying the exact same operations. Leading to the problem that we can't (easily) invoke that check at the point in time when the resource needs to be registered.

Beyond that, this duplication doesn't look very elegant, and I am wondering if there is a "more canonical" way of solving this?

EDIT: another option would be to add the check into the existing resource, into each resource, but that means: doing the check for each operation. Which can easily be forgotten when adding new operations.

I envision something like having:

- a "base resource", that gets registered
- when *any* operation is invoked on that resource, the request should be "delegated", depending on that underlying feature
- either to a resource that just gives 501 always
- or to the "real" resource that does the real work

And ideally, without duplicating checking code, or duplicating operation end point specs.

Comment: I don't get it, wan't this suppose to be a simple `if(someCondition) throw 501 else do the normal processing`?

Comment: I don't further understand how do you plan to solve this with your current approach to be honest :( why would you need to duplicate them? do you have an override in mind? care to explain to me may be?

Comment: the thing that bother me is `@Path("whatever")` would duplicate - in Spring at least - you obviously can't have this, since you map to the same path...

Comment: I agree with @Eugene  : Using the same Rest endpoints should not be possible (With or without Spring).  You should probably use a JAX RS interceptor/filter. I don't have time to write an answer now but you can do it :)

Comment: Take a look at [this for Jersey filters](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9365).

Comment: @davidxxx even if you write an interceptor, you might "forget" (as the OP wants) to insert the proper logic for the ones that should fail... I guess

Comment: I got it to work ... Paul, thanks for your input, same to @Eugene. Please consider removing no longer required comments ;-)

Comment: @davidxxx Finally, I got it to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the suggestion given by user Samsotha, I implemented a simple [filter](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9365), which is then "connected" via [name binding](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9675), like:

```
@Path("whatever")
@MyNewFilter
public class WhateverResource {
...
```

And:

```
@MyNewFilter
public class MyNewFilterImpl implements ContainerRequestFilter {
  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {      
    if (... feature is enabled )) {
        ... nothing to do
    } else {
        context.abortWith(
                Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_IMPLEMENTED).entity("not implemented").build());
    }
}
```

The major advantage of this approach is the fact that one can annotate individual operations, but also a whole resource, such as my `WhateverResource`. The latter will make sure that *any* operation within that resource is going through the filter!

( further details can be found in any decent Jersey tutorial, like the one at [baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/jersey-filters-interceptors) )

Comment: of course, now you have to "remember" to annotate your classes... ;)

Comment: Sure, but that is a *one time* thing. And of course: much more straight forward. Now that we got this concept "working" ... whenever we need such filtering, we will know in advance, and annotate the resource class when it is first written. That is very much different from remembering to annotate *each* new method within a class.

Comment: my point was different. create a safety-net test... scan every class you have on your path (in a certain package of course) and see which ones are annotated with `@Path`, if they miss `@MyFilter` - fail

Comment: That isn't our requirement. We have an existing component that gets enhanced with additional API endpoints. For the *new* ones we have to ensure that they check "enablement", but not for old, existing APIs. So we only filter *selected* classes, the majority goes without the filter!